# Manipulating single item in list

Tags: haskell

```hs
import Control.Lens
import Data.List (filter)
import Data.Time
import Data.Text

data Vehicle = Vehicle
  { _name :: Text
  , _admissionDate :: Day
  , _vehicleId :: Int
  , _refuels :: [Refuel]
  }

makeLenses ''Vehicle

data Refuel = Refuel
  { distance :: Int
  , volume :: Double
  , pricePerUnit :: Double
  }

addRefuel :: Refuel -> Vehicle -> Vehicle
addRefuel refuel = refuels <>~ [refuel]

addRefuelToVehicle :: Int -> refuel -> [Vehicle] -> [Vehicle]
addRefuelToVehicle vehicleId refuel vehicles =
  case vehicle of
    -- Not actual implementation
    Nothing -> error "Vehicle not found"
    Just v ->
      let
        vehicle = addRefuel v refuel
      -- Add everything that is not the vehicle and add modified vehicle
      filter (\v' -> v' ˆ. vehicleId /= vehicleId) vehicles ++ [vehicle]
  where
    vehicle = find (\v -> v ^. vehicleId == vehicleId) vehicles

vehicles =
  [ Vehicle { _name = "Car 1", _admissionDate = fromGregorian 2006 4 6, _vehicleId = 1, _refuels = []
  , Vehicle { _name = "Car 2", _admissionDate = fromGregorian 2013 7 22, _vehicleId = 2, _refuels = []
  ]
```

In this example I want to add a `Refuel` to the `_refuels` list of the vehicle with `_vehicleId = 1`. In an object-oriented language, I would solve it like this:

```
// Ignoring the fact that it may be null
vehicles
  .find { it._vehicleId == 1 }
  ._refuels
  .append(refuel)
```

How would you go around and solve this in Haskell?

Comment: I would recommend trying to write `addRefuel :: Int -> Refuel -> [Vehicle] -> [Vehicle]` without using lenses first, if you haven't already.

Comment: I have that function already. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: But the question still stands on how to manipulate that single item, even without lenses and knowing the index of the element @chepner.

Comment: You don't, really; you create a new list that contains a new `Vehicle` that has a new `Refuel` list containing the refuel. Remember, all the values are immutable.

Comment: Underneath, the compiler will recognize which values can be reused, so this doesn't involve as much work behind the scenes as your code would imply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it very similar to your OO code:

```
vehicles & traverse
         . filtered ((==1) . _vehicleId)
         . refuels
         <>~ [refuel]
```

N.B.: this will update *all* vehicles with matching IDs, and if there's none it'll just silently do nothing. Maybe not the behavious you want.

Comment: I like this answer. You made a small typo with `vehicleId` (leading underscore). Wouldn't `<>~ [refuel]` also work?

Comment: No, it must actually be `_vehicleId` there. `<>~` is fine, sure.

Comment: `filteredBy (vehicleId.only 1)`, using the `only` prism, would also work.

Comment: @danidiaz Which package exports `filteredBy`? I've both tried importing `Control.Lens` and `Control.Lens.Combinators`, but none of which seem to export it.

Comment: @DevNebulae `filteredBy` wasn't added to "lens" until version 4.18 http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/changelog

Answer (score 1):

Without using lenses, you would write a function like

```
addRefuel :: ID  -- vehicle id
          -> Refuel  -- refueling data
          -> [Vehicle] -- list of vehicles, one of which you want to update
          -> [Vehicle] -- list of vehicles after the update
addRefuel _ _ [] = []
addRefuel vid r (v:vs) | _vehicleId v == vid = v { _refuel = r : _refuel v} : vs
                       | otherwise = v : addRefuel vid r vs
```

You can call this on your `vehicles` list, but then you pass the return value to whatever code will use your updated list.

Comment: What if the `vehicleId` wouldn't be 1, but instead would somethingbe like 129?

Comment: That's a typo; I meant to use the argument `i` (renamed `vid` in the updated answer).